# Error in JDBC create table and insert in amazon redshift

Tags: r, amazon-redshift, rjdbc

I am using amazon redshift with R. I got the connection working. I wanted to create some database tables and insert some data into them through R. However, I ran into some issues while doing so

```
# Set the Java Environment
# For 64 bit connections
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_121')

# For 32 bit connections
#Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_121')


# Load libraries if they haven't already
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)

# Get the driver
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver",   
                   classPath="drivers/RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.1.1001.jar")

# Connect to the database
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, 
                            "server",
                            "username", "password")
```

The database is connected, without issues. Now I wanted to create a table and insert data into it. I was using `sqlCreateTable` and `sqlAppendTable` to create and insert data into the table.

```
# Create a table iris, and insert the data into it

sql_required <- sqlCreateTable(jdbcConnection, "iris_table1", iris)

tbl_create <-  dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql_required)
```

However, the above command results in the following error.

```
# Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
#                                Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for CREATE TABLE "iris_table1" (
#                                  "Sepal.Length" DOUBLE PRECISION,
#                                  "Sepal.Width" DOUBLE PRECISION,
#                                  "Petal.Length" DOUBLE PRECISION,
#                                  "Petal.Width" DOUBLE PRECISION,
#                                  "Species" VARCHAR(255)
#                                )
# ([JDBC Driver]com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSISimpleRowCountResult 
#   cannot be cast to com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.interfaces.IResultSet)
```

Nevertheless, the table is created and will be listed by the following command

```
sql_required <- "SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG=\'demodata\'"

tables_in_reshift <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql_required)
tail(tables_in_reshift, 1)

#   table_name
# 141 iris_table1
```

I can even insert the data

```
sql_required <- sqlAppendTable(jdbcConnection, "iris_table1", head(iris))


tbl_insert <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql_required)
```

However, this will also result in following error.

```
# Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
#                                Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for INSERT INTO "iris_table1"
#                              ("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")
#                              VALUES
#                              (5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'),
#                              (4.9, 3, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'),
#                              (4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'setosa'),
#                              (4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'),
#                              (5, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'),
#                              (5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, 'setosa')
# ([JDBC Driver]com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.impl.DSISimpleRowCountResult 
# cannot be cast to com.amazon.dsi.dataengine.interfaces.IResultSet)
#
```

Nevertheless, the data will be inserted, as the following command returns 6 records

```
sql_required <- "SELECT * from iris_table1"

inserted_dat <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql_required)


#    sepal.length sepal.width petal.length petal.width species
# 1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 3          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# 4          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 5          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Although the program works, I am concerned with the errors. 
So, my questions are:

What is the error trying to explain and how do I get rid of it?
Is there a better way (faster, more efficient) to create a table and insert data into redshift using `RJDBC`? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I was of the initial opinion that running command such as

```
sqlCreateTable(jdbcConnection, "iris_table5", iris)
```

should be enough to create table but it doesn't create table neither does

```
sqlAppendTable(jdbcConnection, "iris_table1", head(iris))
```

append data to the database table.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the very same error. I was running the query in SQL workbench. So it is definitely not a problem with R. 
It looks like a redshift error. I also changed the JDBC version but continued getting the same error. Tested the query with a colleague who is using the same JDBC version and it worked perfectly for her. 
I think the preferred syntax in redshift is CTAS statement. The CTAS version of the same query worked fine. My solution was to switch to CTAS syntax. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CTAS_examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Of the following two commands:

```
sql_required <- sqlCreateTable(jdbcConnection, "iris_table1", iris)
tbl_create <-  dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql_required)
```

only the first call is needed to create a table.  From the [documentation for dbGetQuery()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DBI/versions/0.5-1/topics/dbGetQuery):

> This function is for SELECT queries only.

But you are not doing a select, you are creating a table.  The same holds true for your call here to insert data:

```
sql_required <- sqlAppendTable(jdbcConnection, "iris_table1", head(iris))
```

So you should just remove those unnecessary calls to `dbGetQuery()` and this should resolve those errors.

I wouldn't expect this to be necessary, but you may have to call `dbCommit()` to close the transaction:

```
dbCommit(jdbcConnection)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was of the same opinion and I did try that initially but those didn't create a table and also didn't append the data. I have updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: @discipulus From what I read this should not be necessary.  It sounds as if a transaction is not being committed.  You can try using `dbCommit()` after your DML statements.

Comment: Interestingly! It doesn't help. `dbCommit(jdbcConnection)` returns true but when I run query: `inserted_dat <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, "SELECT * from iris_table1")`, it returns an error `Error in .jcall(conn@jc, "Ljava/sql/Statement;", "createStatement") : 
  java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon][JDBC](10040) Cannot use commit while Connection is in auto-commit mode.` Running the same command second time works but data is not appended to the table.

Comment: I think you have a problem with Redshift then, not R.  You should check Redshift's documentation.

Comment: If you close your R session, does the data appear in the table the next time you check?

Comment: Yes! It appears, the issue seems to be independent of Rsession as well as dates :-)

Comment: My guess is that this is more of a Firebase issue than having to do with R.

Comment: I absolutely agree. I have written to the AWS. I will update with their feedback here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. If you look at the package documentation, you'll find:

`dbSendQuery` and `dbSendUpdate` submit a SQL query to the database. The difference between the two is only that `dbSendUpdate` is used with `DBML` queries and thus doesn't return any result set.

So using **`dbSendUpdate`** instead of `dbSendQuery` works for me.